# VBA: Saving a Exported XML with a predefined file name with a time stamp

Tags: xml, vba, excel

So I can get this to work where it exports the XML:

```
Sub ExportXML()
'
' ExportXML Macro
'
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("XmlExport")
'
End Sub
```

And this works, to save the actual Excel doc with a specific predefined place ("C:....") and name (Value from Cell A10) with a time stamp:

```
Sub SaveMyWorkbook()
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sCurrDir As String
    Dim sName As Variant
    Dim strdate As String

    sName = [A10] 'value from A1
    strdate = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
    ' save current directory, and change to desired starting directory
    sCurrDir = CurDir
    ChDrive "C:\....."
    ChDir "C:\....."

    vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=sName & strdate, _
        fileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls), *.xls", _
        Title:="My custom save dialog")

    If vFile <> False Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vFile
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a valid path" 'cancel
    End If
    ' change back to initial current directory
    ChDrive sCurrDir
    ChDir sCurrDir

End Sub
```

But I am hoping to have the export run and for it to save to specific predefined place ("C:....") and name (Value from Cell A10) with a time stamp. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How complex is the XML export?  Have you considered writing it out directly?  Eg: http://www.professionalexcel.com/2014/04/export-excel-table-range-to-xml-using-vba/   That would give you more control.

Comment: @ Tim Williams: We needed to map the XML to the document. There are hundreds of nodes and arrays. I really need to use the export functionality. I wish I didn't. :)

Comment: @Tim Williams: Forgot to mention the data comes from a 8 different tabs. Basically we are using the excel sheet as a intake form to create a data file.

Comment: This is the first time I am posting to a message board so if I am doing this wrong please let me know,

Comment: Sorry - can't help here: I've never used the built-in XMLexport tool.

Comment: thanks for giving it a look over and providing an option. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out. Instead of using a command to hit the ribbon button I found the actual command for exporting the XML.

```
Sub ExportXML()
'
' ExportXML Macro
'
Dim objMapToExport As XmlMap

 Set objMapToExport = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("DocumentRequests_Map")

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData [c12] & [c9] & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".xml", objMapToExport


'This opens the folder so you can see the saved file
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & [c12], vbNormalFocus)

'
End Sub
```